# Cannot Plot Time alone as x-axis >> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to plot a graph of Time (6:00 am to 6:00 pm) against temperature and other parameters
but I have been struggling all week

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime
import random
```

```
df = pd.read_excel('g.xlsx')
```

```
TIME    TEMP    RH  WS  NOISE
0   06:00:00    26.3    78.4    0.1 69.2
1   06:10:00    26.8    77.4    0.0 82.0
2   06:20:00    27.1    76.8    0.2 81.0
3   06:30:00    27.1    76.4    0.3 74.0
4   06:40:00    27.4    75.4    0.4 74.0
... ... ... ... ... ...
68  17:20:00    32.5    57.7    0.5 76.1
69  17:30:00    31.8    60.6    2.2 73.4
70  17:40:00    31.4    60.8    0.4 71.8
71  17:50:00    31.2    61.3    0.2 77.3
72  18:00:00    30.9    62.3    2.2 78.1
```

even when I try to convert the column to date time

```
df['TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['TIME'],format= '%H:%M:%S' ).dt.time
```

and I try plotting

```
plt.plot(df.TIME, df.TEMP)
```

I get this error message >> TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

please assist me

```
df.plot works instead of plt.plot
```

but the downside is I am unable to treat the figure as fig and manipulate the graph

```
df.plot(x="TIME", y=["TEMP"])
df.plot.line(x="TIME", y=["TEMP"])
```

[image]

The downside with this is the time should start at the beginning 6:00 am and end at 6:00 pm, but it's unable to be manipulated, adding figure doesn't work

```
fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(5, 5))
```

Thanks and waiting for your fast response

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an axes to `df.plot`:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
df.plot(x='TIME', y='TEMP', ax=ax)
ax.set_xlim(6*60*60, 18*60*60) # time in seconds
```

output:

[image: pandas line plot]

It looks like scatter plot is not working well with datetime. You can use this workaround:

```
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(5, 5))
df.plot(x='TIME', y='TEMP', ax=ax, style='.')
ax.set_xlim(6*60*60, 18*60*60)
```

[image: pandas fake scatter plot]

Comment: what if you want to do a scatter or bar chart, can you have other options for df.plot? like scatter or bar I also want to set the limit to 6*00*00 and 18*00*00

Comment: Use `df.plot.scatter` or `df.plot.bar` (takes only 1 column by default). Also "6*00*00" would mean midnight (0 seconds), "6*60*60" is 6 hours * 60 minutes * 60 seconds

Comment: when I put df.plot.scatter I get this error float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time' and its an empty chat, however, df.plot.bar only gives an empty chat

Comment: my final question buddy, since the plt. command doesn't work, how do I use the following commands, plt.savefig,plt.legend, plt.xlabel, plt.tick_params, plt.minorticks_on(), plt.semilogx etc

Comment: It seems that scatter does not work well with datetime. I provided a workaround. The plt commands do work, just they apply to the last active plot. All those commandsare also available through the fig or ax instances (e.g. fig.savefig),I'll let you search the matplotlib documentation for that.

Comment: Thanks, @mozway, my sincere appreciation for all the support! how can I add to your rep? could you also share your GitHub?

Comment: @esuo2 if you're happy with the answer feel free to accept/upvote it ;)

Comment: Hello guys, am back again after searching trying and still failing
How do I do a multipanel plot
let's say 3 rows and 4 columns

am also unable to define values for x and y

for example after defining x = df[TIME] and defining y = df[TEMP]
I still have to use 
```
df.plot(x='TIME', y='TEMP', ax=ax), suggested by mozway, cant i just say df.plot(x, y, ax=ax), bcos I get errors
```

{@esuo2 if you're happy with the answer feel free to accept/upvote it ;)} >>> how do I do that

Comment: please any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem in which the same error message arose, but *not using Pandas*. My code went something like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
import matplotlib.pyplot at plt

x = [datetime(2022,1,1, 6).time(),
     datetime(2022,1,1, 9).time(),
     datetime(2022,1,1, 12).time(),
     datetime(2022,1,1, 15).time(),
     datetime(2022,1,1, 18).time()]
y = [1,5,7,5,1]  #(shape of solar intensity)

fig = plt.plot()
ax  = fig.subplot(111)
ax.plot(x,y)
```

The problem was that matplotlib could not plot `datetime.time` objects. I got around the problem by instead plotting `y` against `x1=[1,2,3,4,5]` and then setting the x-ticks:

```
ax.set_xticks(x1, ["6am","9am","12pm","3pm","6pm"])
```